# Unable to configure server for deploying rules using IBM ODM

Tags: websphere, business-rules, ibm-odm

I followed this YouTube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIJ-VLkuw0s

at 10:15 min, they have added "http://localhost:9080/res" as server URL
when I tried the same , I got below error

```
The location "http://localhost::9080/" is not a valid file system path:  : is an invalid character in resource name 'localhost::9080'.
```

I downloaded WebSphere from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/websphere-liberty-developers

WebSphere Liberty Web Profile 8 21.0.0.4 file(93MB)

unzipped the downloaded file
I ran server from location by running bat file from location

```
C:\Users\vaageesh\wlp-webProfile8-21.0.0.4\wlp\bin\server.bat
```

still when I added "http://localhost:9080/res" as server URL
Target servers tab in
"Create Deployment configuration" step, its throwing error

could you guide me exactly how to configure server and pre-requisites needed to deploy rules on this server with configurations we have done

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to unselect "Local Rule ...." to have a proper wizard that is relative to Web deploiement.
The screenshot you are mentioning is about local directory folder deploiement.
See picture.

[image]

Best
Emmanuel